# ora_rowscn with inner join oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query

I tried this..

```
select "Rental".*,ora_rowscn from "Rental"
```

It is working perfectly.

But when I join it to another table (which is the real req) like this

```
 SELECT "Rental".*, ORA_ROWSCN FROM "Rental"
  inner join "UserBranch" on  "UserBranch"."fkBranchId" = "Rental"."fkBranchId"
  WHERE "Rental"."IsDeleted"='N' ;
```

It's giving me  exception

```
ORA-00904: "ORA_ROWSCN": invalid identifier
```

I even tried this

```
select ora_rowscn,"myTable"."pkRentalId" from (select "Rental"."pkRentalId"  from "Rental"
  inner join "UserBranch" on  "UserBranch"."fkBranchId" = "Rental"."fkBranchId"
  WHERE "Rental"."IsDeleted"='N' ) "myTable"
```

same exception

tried this too

```
select "myTable".*,"myTable".ora_rowscn as "TimeStamp" from (select "Rental".*  from "Rental"  inner join "UserBranch" on  "UserBranch"."fkBranchId" = "Rental"."fkBranchId"
  WHERE "Rental"."IsDeleted"='N' ) "myTable"
```

same exception

please help

Comment: Once you perform a join, doesn't `ora_rowscn` become ambiguous as to which table's row data you are trying to pull?

Comment: see the edited version of my question